# Saving a base 64 encoded image in MongoDB GridFS

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, base64, gridfs

I have a web service that takes the content of a canvas tag and saves it into a MongoDB GridFS store.

The code below works, however it requires saving the image to disk before sending it to MongoDB.

```
    Using postBody As Stream = Request.InputStream
        ' Get the body of the HTTP POST (the data:image/png)
        postBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Dim imageData As String = New StreamReader(postBody).ReadToEnd

        Dim base64Data = Regex.Match(imageData, "data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups("data").Value
        Dim data As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data)

        Using stream = New MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length)
            Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream)

            Dim directory = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/")
            Dim file = String.Concat(directory, id, ".png")
            img.Save(file, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

            Using fs = New FileStream(file, FileMode.Open)
                db.GridFS.Upload(fs, id & ".png")
            End Using

        End Using
    End Using
```

Is there a better way, perhaps without the need to persist it to disk before uploading to MongoDB?

Comment: Why not just pass it the memory stream, with `Position` set back to `0`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, just use the *Stream* as an argument to [Upload](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/9cc50630-21f7-3d91-cb05-9f598188a533.htm) instead of writing out to file.

And also note that you **do not have to** convert to base64 in order to send the file via GridFS (or a plain mongo field for that matter). The input can be binary, unless of course you *always* want your data base64 encoded for your convenience.